# Ag-grid set filter menu tab - how to make it re-sizable?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need to make re-sizable the set filter menu tab on a column and in the ag-grid documentation I only find how to override the menu's fixed width as below:

```
 *.ag-set-filter-list {
      width: 500px !important;
  }*
```

Is there any way to have this set filter menu to re-size with the content or to allow user to change the size?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried width:auto ?

Comment: I tried with width:auto but nothing changed. Also I realized that what I really need is to allow users to resize by dragging the popup's right bottom corner. If I allow to auto-size by it's content I might have an extremely large popup and I don't want that. Thanks

Comment: Ummmm... max-width ?

Answer (score 0):

I know your request dates back from 2 years ago, but Ag-grid just released what you requested. It's their Issue AG-4028, listed here: https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog